# ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ!

Tags: c++

> При компиляции ошибка:
> ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class Mass __cdecl operator*(class Mass &,long)" (??D@YA?AV?$Mass@J@@AAV0@J@Z) в функции _main. lab18.3 D:\Лабараторки\lab18\lab18.3\lab18.3\Source.obj 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Mass
{
private:
    long double* p;
    int sizemass;
public:
    Mass() {
        sizemass = 1;
        p = new long double[1];
        p[0] = 10;
    }
    Mass(long x)
    {
        sizemass = x;
        p = new long double[x];
    }
    Mass(long x, long double znach)
    {
        sizemass = x;
        p = new long double[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            p[i] = znach;
        }
    }
    Mass(const Mass<T>& object)
    {
        this->p = object.p;
        this->sizemass = sizemass;
    }
    ~Mass() {
        delete[] p;
    }
    void out(void) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizemass; i++) {
            cout << p[i];
        }
    }
    Mass<T> operator = (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator += (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] + znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator -= (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] - znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator *= (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0;i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] * znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator [] (int x) {
        return this->p[x];
    }
    friend Mass<T> operator + (Mass<T>& object1, T znach);
    friend Mass<T> operator - (Mass<T>& object1, T znach);
    friend Mass<T> operator * (Mass<T>& object1, T znach);
};

template <class T>
Mass<T> operator + (Mass<T>& object1, T znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] + znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
Mass<T> operator - (Mass<T>& object1, T znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] - znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
Mass<T> operator * (Mass<T>& object1, T znach) {
    Mass temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] * znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    Mass<long> v(8);
    Mass<long> m(6);
    m + 1;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Довольно интересный вопрос. Проблема здесь, насколько я понял, в связке шаблонов и дружественных функций.

Итак, чтобы всё заработало, нужно:

1. Продублировать `template<class T>` перед объявлением дружественных
   функций внутри класса.
2. Явно указать тип второго слагаемого в 4ой строке функции `main` с
   помощью строкового литерала.

По итогу код будет выглядеть так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Mass
{
private:
    long double* p;
    int sizemass;
public:
    Mass() {
        sizemass = 1;
        p = new long double[1];
        p[0] = 10;
    }
    Mass(long x)
    {
        sizemass = x;
        p = new long double[x];
    }
    Mass(long x, long double znach)
    {
        sizemass = x;
        p = new long double[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            p[i] = znach;
        }
    }
    Mass(const Mass<T>& object)
    {
        this->p = object.p;
        this->sizemass = sizemass;
    }
    ~Mass() {
        delete[] p;
    }
    void out(void) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizemass; i++) {
            cout << p[i];
        }
    }
    Mass<T> operator = (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator += (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] + znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator -= (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] - znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator *= (T znach) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->sizemass; i++) {
            this->p[i] = this->p[i] * znach;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Mass<T> operator [] (int x) {
        return this->p[x];
    }
    
    template <class T> // !!!
    friend Mass<T> operator + (Mass<T>& object1, T znach);
    friend Mass<T> operator - (Mass<T>& object1, T znach);
    friend Mass<T> operator * (Mass<T>& object1, T znach);
};

template <class T>
Mass<T> operator + (Mass<T>& object1, T znach) {
    Mass<T> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] + znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
Mass<T> operator - (Mass<T>& object1, T znach) {
    Mass<T> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] - znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
Mass<T> operator * (Mass<T>& object1, T znach) {
    Mass<T> temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < object1.sizemass; i++) {
        temp.p[i] = object1.p[i] * znach;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    Mass<long> v(8);
    Mass<long> m(6);
    m + 1l; // l показывает, что 1 имеет тип long
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Первый пункт нашёл [здесь](https://norseev.ru/2018/04/13/friend-function-for-template-class/), погуглив про связку шаблонов и друзей.

Затрудняюсь назвать причины необходимости дублирования `template <class T>` перед объявлением дружественных функций. Возможно, это просто жёсткое требование синтаксиса, а может, за этим стоит что-то большее. В любом случае, надеюсь, найдётся эксперт, который прояснит ситуацию в комментарии или отдельном ответе.

Насчёт второго пункта всё проще – число `1`, не являясь переменной, у которой указан тип, по умолчанию имеет тип `int`, если иное не указано с помощью литерала. Таким образом, когда Вы делаете `m + 1`, у Вас вызывается шаблонная функция `Mass<T> operator + (Mass<T>& object1, T znach)`, где первый аргумент имеет тип `Mass<long>`, а второй аргумент – `int`. Но т.к., согласно шаблону, параметр первого аргумента и тип второго должны совпадать, необходимо `1` явно привести к типу `long` с помощью литерала `l`.